On Unity3D Mirror Networking, how to implement Additive Scenes without Changing and Unloading Scenes on Clients?
My Use Case:
I have a set of scenes that are effectively rooms in a dungeon. I want to load them all on both host and client. In the future, I want to implement interactivity across rooms (e.g. a wall from one room is blown up, showing the other room), so it's important to have all scenes loading on both host and client.
What I tried

Looked at Scene Interest Management examples, but they unload the scene on the client which doesn't support my use case https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/manual/interest-management/scene
I tried loading the scene on the Server and then calling NetworkServer.Spawn() on the objects, but it threw the error: BoneClam (7) [netId=11] was already spawned. , depsite the Client not having the objects
I tried loading the scene on both client and server via SceneManager but the NetworkIdentities do not connect (they remain disabled on the client)

